Telegram Show Popup message box use telegram api and telebot in python
how to show popup message box in telegram, use telebot python library like below picture:
enter image description here
Or give me a keyword related to this message box so that I can search about it and get the answer
I tried several methods, but I did not get the result

The given screenshot is actually of Enabling Proxy on Telegram. Which is more like a default interface. You cannot create a similar pop up box.
But you can still create a pop-up box like the following:

This is created with answerCallbackQuery method along with passing show_alert set to true. You can show this type of pop-up alerts when user taps on a inline button that creates a callback query.
Check the documentation of answerCallbackQuery for more details.
